# How to obtain the seconds of a day from the timestamp in the index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

Then I am obtaining the hours minutes and seconds as:

```
train_data['time'] = train_data.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

which results in the last column. Then I would like to get the seconds by simply multiplying the hours by 3600, the minutes by 60 and then adding all three. However I have no clue about how to do it in all the rows at once without using a loop.

If I access individually the values as `train_data['time'].values[0]` it behaves as a string and then it is clear how to proceed, however if I just try to access the values in any other way I get errors.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for convert it to timedeltas and then [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
train_data['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(train_data.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `sum`, `map`, `zip`, `str.split` and `int`:

```
t = "01:10:34"

as_seconds = sum( f*t for f,t in zip((3600,60,1),map(int,t.split(":"))))

print(as_seconds) # 4234
```

and apply this to all your data.

The **wiser choice** would be to use the `datetime.timedelta` and get its [.total_seconds()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) though as pointed out by [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62469725/7505395)